# Casting object to generic type instance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I have a class `Option<T>` defined like this:

```
class Option<T>
{
     T Value { get; set; }
     bool HasValue { get; }
}
```

At some point of my code, an instance of this class is sent to me via callback as `object` (passed inside `value`)

```
private void Callback(object value)
{
}
```

I want to cast the value to an `Option<T>`, but I don't know the type `T` at compile time.
How do I "upcast" the instance to be able to check, for example, the `Value` property?

Comment: "_I want to cast the value to an Option<T>, but I don't know the type T at compile time_" Then you cannot cast, because casting is a compile time concept. You would need to use reflection or `dynamic`.

Comment: How would you want to check the `Value` property if you don't know the type? Can you give us a snippet of what you would want to do with that `Option<T>` object, that perhaps does not compile in C# but conveys your intent?

Comment: If you can change the class implement a non-generic `IOption` interface with `object Value` property.

Comment: How are you supposed to cast if you don't know the type to cast to...? Not possible. `Option<T>` is just a blueprint for a type. At runtime `T` is an actual type.

Comment: So, how do you use Reflection to check HasValue?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you told us in the comments was that you want to access `HasValue`. That one is easy - create an interface

```
public interface IOption
{
    bool HasValue { get; }
}

class Option<T> : IOption
{
     T Value { get; set; }
     bool HasValue { get; }
}
```

And cast the `object` you receive to `IOption`. If you need to also extract the value, you'll need an additional interface with a [covariant type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

```
public interface IOption<out T> : IOption
{
    T Value { get; }
}

class Option<T> : IOption<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    bool HasValue { get; }
}
```

then you will be able to cast your `object` to `IOption<object>` and it will succeed for any `T`, allowing you to retrieve `Value` as an `object`. You won't be able to set it, though.

Comment: I forgot to say that Option<T> is a third-party class, so I cannot make it implement an arbitrary interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all possibilities you can use pattern matching:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            object someOption = new Option<DateTime>() { Value = DateTime.Now};
            
            switch (someOption)
            {
                case Option<DateTime> dt: 
                    Console.WriteLine($"Date: {dt.Value}");
                    break;
                case Option<string> str:
                    Console.WriteLine($"String: {str}");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Otherwise this might be a solution for you. I used a conecpt like this some times when I need to pass the object to other generic methods or use it in generic types.

```
        interface IOptionHandler
        {
            void Handle(object option);
        }
        static class OptionHandler
        {
            public static IOptionHandler Create(Type targetType)
            {
                // normally you would check if it really is an Option<T> 
                // by providing some non-generic interface like IOption
                // we skip this part

                var typeParam = targetType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                var helperType = typeof(Helper<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
                return (IOptionHandler) Activator.CreateInstance(helperType);
            }

            class Helper<T> : IOptionHandler
            {
                public void Handle(object option)
                {
                    // in this context you can use all the generic powers again
                    Option<T> myOlOption = (Option<T>) option;

                    List<Option<T>> whatever = new List<Option<T>>();
                    whatever.Add(myOlOption);

                    Console.WriteLine($"{myOlOption.Value.GetType()}: {myOlOption.Value}");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            object someOption = new Option<DateTime>() { Value = DateTime.Now};

            var handler = OptionHandler.Create(someOption.GetType());
            handler.Handle(someOption);
        }
```

I usually cache the created helper objects but that's totally use-case dependent.